# Debug.Assert Behavior in Unity

Tags: unity

Is this normal behaviour that Unity continues to run after a condition in a `Debug.Assert` statement was NOT met when I launch the game within the Editor? I can see the assertion in the console output, but still would expect it to stop the game. `Development build` and `Script Debugging` are turned on in my player settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know how a specific method is supposed to behave normally, then a good place to look is [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Assert.html). In the case of `Debug.Assert`, it reads:

> Assert a condition and logs an error message to the Unity console on failure.

It says nothing about stopping the game. So yes, this is normal behavior.

And by the way: Your player build settings are only relevant if you *build* the project. They are not relevant when you test a game from the editor.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. That helped.